# how to convert text to proper JSON in R

Tags: r, json

i have this code in php:

```
$n = '[{"area":30,"ind":[5,5,4,5,4.14,3.75],"isCluster":true},{"area":31,"ind":[],"isCluster":false}]';

$command = "\"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.0\bin\Rscript.exe\" C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\CKmeans1D.R $n";
exec($command, $output);

print_r($output);
```

it execute the CKmeans1D.R to run R file, and in R i have this code:

```
library(jsonlite)

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

x <- fromJSON(args[1])
x
```

after printing out the output which is the x it error in the php error logs, and this is the error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                     [{area:30,ind:[5,5,4,5,4.14,3.75]
                     (right here) ------^
Execution halted
```

however before adding this line x <- fromJSON(args[1]) i printed out the args[1] and it returns with this:

```
[{area:30,ind:[5,5,4,5,4.14,3.75],isCluster:true},{area:31,ind:[],isCluster:false}]
```

the double qoutes are removed in every keys.

how am i able to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building the command in your PHP code, enclose the JSON string `n` with single quotes :

```php
$command = "\"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.0\bin\Rscript.exe\" C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\CKmeans1D.R '$n'";
```

Testing without PHP, `argtest.R` :

```r
jsonlite::fromJSON(commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1])
```

Rscript from command line:

```bash
$ Rscript.exe argtest.R '[{"area":30,"ind":[5,5,4,5,4.14,3.75],"isCluster":true},{"area":31,"ind":[],"isCluster":false}]'
  area                                ind isCluster
1   30 5.00, 5.00, 4.00, 5.00, 4.14, 3.75      TRUE
2   31                                        FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a JavaScript code in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/dfkaye/dcb060a13470de8119833dc56933563f) whose purpose is to fix JSON strings. We can use it with the help of the **V8** package to fix your JSON string.

Firstly, copy the JavaScript code below and save it under the name ***jsonNormalize.js***:

```js
// https://gist.github.com/dfkaye/dcb060a13470de8119833dc56933563f
// copyright David Kaye

/**
 * Helper functions and queries for normalize() method.
 */

const BLANK_LINES = /([\n](\s)*(?:\n))/g;
const LINE_COMMENTS = /[\"\']*(?:[\s\w]]*)(\/\/[^\n^\"^\}]*)/g;
// Attempt to handle /* */ and /** javadoc style * line * line2 comments */
const MULTILINE_COMMENTS = /[\"\']*(?:\s*)(\/\*+)([^\*]*[\*])([^\/]*[\/])/g;
const SINGLE_QUOTES = /([^\\][\'](?:[^\']*)[\'](?:[^\}^\:^\,]*))/g;
const UNQUOTED_WORDS = /(?:(\,|\:|\{)\s*)([\w]+)/g;

function addQuotes(e) {

  // return booleans unchanged
  if (/false|true/.test(e)) {
    return e;
  }

  // return numbers unchanged
  if (/^\d?\.?\d+$/.test(e)) {
    return e;
  }

  // replaces null, undefined, and NaN with empty string
  if (/null|undefined|NaN/.test(e)) {
    e = '';
  }

  return '"' + e + '"';
}

function replaceUnquoted(m) {
  return m.replace(/\w+/g, addQuotes);
}

/**
 * @method normalize Attempts to fix a JSON string with bare keys (restore
 * missing quotes) and single-quoted keys and values, and remove line comments,
 * block comments, blank lines, etc.
 * @param {string} jsonText
 * @returns {string}
 */

function normalize(jsonText) {
  var fixed = jsonText

    // 18 Oct 2018 - remove comments and blank lines
    // 30 Oct 2018 - preserve quoted comments
    // remove line comments
    .replace(LINE_COMMENTS, e => {

      // Ignore if line comment is quoted.
      return /[\"\']([\s\w]*[\:])?/.test(e[0]) ? e : '';
    })

    // remove multi-line comments
    .replace(MULTILINE_COMMENTS, e => {

      // Ignore if comment is quoted.
      return /[\"\']/.test(e[0]) ? e : '';
    })

    // remove blank lines
    .replace(BLANK_LINES, '\n')

    // 17,18 oct 2018
    // fix single quotes
    // 15 feb 2019
    // escaped apostrophes
    .replace(SINGLE_QUOTES, (m) => {

      /*
       * Replace leading and trailing single quotes with double quotes, trim
       * quoted spaces, ignore quoted apostrophes.
       */

      var t = m.trim();
      var p = m.split(t);
      var r = p[0] + t.replace(/^[\']/, '"') + p[1];

      return r.replace(/([\'])(?:[\s]*)$/, (e) => {
        return '"' + (e.length > 1 ? e.substring(1) : '');
      });
    })

    // 17 october 2018
    // success
    // add missing quotes
    .replace(UNQUOTED_WORDS, replaceUnquoted)

    // 28 December 2019 - fix [01] and { 01: 01 }
    // e.g., replace 01 with "01"
    .replace(/(?=[^\"^\']+)[0]+([1-9)+(?=[^\"^\']+)/g, function (e) {
      return '"' + e + '"';
    })

    // trim it
    .trim();

  return fixed;
}
```

Now it is a child game to fix your JSON string with the **V8** package:

```r
x <- "[{area:30,ind:[5,5,4,5,4.14,3.75],isCluster:true},{area:31,ind:[],isCluster:false}]"

library(V8)
ctx <- v8()

ctx$source("jsonNormalize.js")
ctx$assign("x", x)
ctx$eval("var newx = normalize(x);")
ctx$get("newx")
# "[{\"area\":30,\"ind\":[5,5,4,5,4.14,3.75],\"isCluster\":true},{\"area\":31,\"ind\":[],\"isCluster\":false}]"
```

The double quotes are back!

Maybe this method deserves a small R package. It is useful. Thanks to the author of the gist, David Kaye.

---

## Edit

I've just done the package

```r
remotes::install_github("stla/jsonNormalize")
library(jsonNormalize)
# the keys of the following JSON string are not quoted
jstring <- "[{area:30,ind:[5,4.1,3.7],cluster:true},{ind:[],cluster:false}]"
jsonNormalize(jstring)
# [1] "[{\"area\":30,\"ind\":[5,4.1,3.7],\"cluster\":true},{\"ind\":[],\"cluster\":false}]"
```